# stop or allow closure of a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, preventdefault

I am very confused with this code. I try to allow the window to close if all the validations even the call by ajax are correct. The problem is that when I run preventDefault I can't cancel it anymore. In summary, if I click on the save button, if everything is correct, it closes the modal window and if it is not correct, it cancels the closure. Hope you can help me. Thank you

```
$('#modalAltaReceta').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e){
    var cancel = false;
    var btn_grabar = false;                 
    $("#grabarReceta").click(function() {                           
        var cantidadSinIngreso = 0;                     
        if($("#inputNombreReceta").val().trim()=="") {
            alert("Ingrese un nombre para la receta");
            cancel = true;
        } else if($("#inputIntroReceta").val().trim()=="") {
            alert("Ingrese una introduccion breve");
            cancel = true;
        } else if($("#inputInstruccionesReceta").val().trim()=="") {
            alert("Explique cuales con los pasos para realizar esta receta");
            cancel = true;
        }
        cantidadSinIngreso = 0;
        $(".inputIngredientes").each(function(index, item) {
            if(item.value.trim() == "")
                cantidadSinIngreso++
        });
        
        if(cantidadSinIngreso > 0) {                            
            cancel = true;
            alert("Ingrese por lo menos un ingrediente");                                                   
        } else {
            $.ajax({                                                
                url: 'php/recetas.php',
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',                       
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "tipo_id=grabarReceta&" + $("#frm_nueva_receta").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {   
                    if(data['msg'] == 'ok') {                                                                           
                        cancel = true;
                    }                                       
                }
            });         
            return cancel;      
        }                                                                       
    });
    if(cancel) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false; 
    }

});
```

Comment: Don't nest your events.  Move `$("#grabarReceta").click(` outside of `$('#modalAltaReceta').on('hide.bs.modal'`

Comment: thanks when the entire click event of the save button is executed, the window closes. In that event, how do I cancel the closing of the window?

Comment: Move the `preventDefault` / `stopImmediatePropagation` / `return false` inside the click event.

Comment: But the event that I have to stop is the closure of the modal. How do I do from the other event to do it?

Comment: $('#modalAltaReceta').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e){ event = e;}); $("#grabarReceta").click(function() { event.preventDefault(); return false;});

Comment: TBH, it's a bit unclear which button you're pressing and when.  is #grabarReceta the "save button"?  So you click #grabarReceta and you want a) close dialog if all saves ok?  and b) don't close if not ok?  Just always cancel the hide event and close the dialog yourself (via code) when saved ok.

Comment: That's just what I don't understand how.
The modal window has two buttons, one is save and the other is cancel.
When I press save I want from the click event to keep the modal open if something is not valid and I want to close the window if everything is correct. But I do not know from the click event of the save button to be able to keep the modal window open or closed. I tried with $ ("# id -"). Modal ('hide) and (' show ') but I can't cancel the closing

Comment: Sounds like you're ok if they cancel->close or [x]->close (which is good UI) - so it's just your save button is also closing.   Change the save button so it never closes the modal, then close it in code.  How you do that depends on which version of bootstrap you - which version is it?   eg *could* be to remove `data-dismiss="modal"` `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`  (make sure it's lowercase modal, not Modal).  Look for errors in the console as `.Modal` would likely give an error.

Comment: Hello, I was already without data-dismiss="modal"  $('# myModal'). modal ('hide') doesn't work. The version is 5.1

Comment: Well it won't be `# myModal` (with a space) and it won't be "myModal" unless you've renamed your modal.   Try `$('#modalAltaReceta').modal("hide")`

Comment: Looks like bootstrap 5.0 [has different mehods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options) - try `bootstrap.Modal.getInstance($("#modalAltaReceta")[0]).hide();`